# R regression stepwise - Change entry/removal criteria, and model variable significance

Tags: r, regression, lm

I've been using the lm regression function and using a stepwise regression. Unfortunately the stepwise doesn't seem to allow much flexibility. Entry/Removal Criteria and Significance can't be adjusted.

Using the mtcars, i run these codes

```
FitAll <- lm(mpg ~ . ,data=mtcars) # Fit reg model with all variables
FitStart <- lm(mpg~1,data=mtcars) # Fit reg model with just intercept
step(FitStart, direction = "both"  , scope=formula(FitAll)) # stepwise, "both"=forward&backward
```

It tells me the stepwise stops with 3 variables in the model, wt + cyl + hp. When I run a regression model with these, I find that some of the variables are not significant at 5%.

```
fit <- lm(formula = mpg ~ wt + cyl + hp, data = mtcars)
summary(fit)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 38.75179    1.78686  21.687  < 2e-16 ***
wt          -3.16697    0.74058  -4.276 0.000199 ***
cyl         -0.94162    0.55092  -1.709 0.098480 .  
hp          -0.01804    0.01188  -1.519 0.140015
```

Is there a way using this lm and step function to specify entry and exit criteria. Also, there are also times when I want to increase the strictness to all variables significant at 1%. Is there any way to specify entry/exit criteria and significance level with this method? Is there a better package to use?
Any help much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I took a quick look at the docs, and it looks like step() uses the Akakie Information Criteria (AIC) to select models, not a p-value threshold.

Comment: @Bill - thanks for pointing out it is AIC. I found [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97257/stepwise-regression-in-r-critical-p-value) which enables a work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try the package StepReg which appears to offer the options you want

```
# install.packages("StepReg")

library(StepReg)

stepwise(mtcars, 
         y = "mpg", 
         selection = "bidirection", 
         select = "SL", 
         sle = .01, 
         sls = .01)
#> $process
#>   Step EffectEntered EffectRemoved EffectNumber    Select
#> 1    0     intercept                          1  1.000000
#> 2    1            wt                          2 -9.859915
#> 3    2           cyl                          3 -2.914801
#> 
#> $variate
#> [1] "intercept" "wt"        "cyl"
```

Comment: that is near perfect, but is there a way to specify "no intercept"?

Comment: None that I can see, not my package and tbh I don't use it.  Obviously you can compute the model after it does it's thing but not sure what the advantage would be in dropping the intercept unless you have some certainty one doesn't exist.

Comment: looking at this further, if you change the sle and sls values it doesn't actually do anything. I've ran this in another stats software parallel (adjusting sle and sls) to see what results occur. If you lower the sle/sls you should get more variables come through. I think this could be a faulty package/function? If anyone is using it, I'd advise to test the criteria thoroughly to see if it's actually doing anything.

Comment: @H.Cheung Thanks for using StepReg R package, I am the author of StepReg. Sorry to reply you late. Actually I had ran some datasets both with StepReg and SAS software before uploading StepReg to CRAN, there are always consistent results. I don't know what exact sle and sls value you changed for your test using this package, 'Select' column of result is the log10(pvalue), when I tried to decrease sle and sls to 0.001, the result changed. It is great if you can share your test result with another stats software parallel (adjusting sle and sls). I can debug it if there are different output.Thanks

Comment: @H.Cheung Besides, it will output less variables if you lower the sls/sle. sls/sle are the significant levels for stay/enter, lower sls/sle means more strict threshold for variable enter/stay in the model. Thanks!